# How to do a progress bar striped?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm working with progress bar, i add the lib ng-simple-progress-bar to work with it https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-simple-progress-bar .

this is my code html:

```
<ng-simple-progress-bar 
     [percent]="30" 
     [color]="'#6e587a'"
     (percentChange)="onPercentChange($event)"
     [height]="'20px'" [backgroundColor]="'#f7f7f7'"
     [progressBarType]="'square'"
     class="stripes">
</ng-simple-progress-bar>
```

I obtain this result:

[image: current result]

But U want to obtain this result:

[image: desired result]

Any help, How to do it?

Comment: color should be a gradient (backgroundImage)  to allow that design you are after . It seems like you do not have this option . This is generating a an inner div with the class `inner-bar`  you might be able to add style for it like `.inner-bar {background-image:repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, blue 0 5px, lightblue 5px 10px) ;}` with your own size and color

Comment: @Robert Harvey i need a ready lib.

Comment: Thanks for every one  it worked, by changing the component  <ng-simple-progress-bar>  by   < ngb-progressbar> https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-progressbar

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
 <ng-simple-progress-bar [percent]="30" [color]="'#6e587a'"
    (percentChange)="onPercentChange($event)"
    [height]="'20px'" [backgroundColor]="'#f7f7f7'"
    [progressBarType]="'square'"
    [striped]="true">
  </ng-simple-progress-bar>
```